# If I give an html element a name, how do i reach to it from php?

Tags: php

If I give an html element a name, how do i reach to it from php?
Can I just put a $ before the given name and use it as a variable or I have to do something else.
I know is a stupid question, but I'm new at these and i can really use your help.

Comment: It is not a stupid question. It shows a complete lack of understanding of how it works. PHP runs server side, HTML is rendered client side. You could refer to an element name in Javascript, NOT in PHP.

Comment: i think it will be easier if you tell us what exactly you try to acheive by accesing the element.

Comment: To get the data you should use $_POST["name"] for post method and $_GET["name"] for get method

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server-side programming language while HTML is a client-side markup language, so you can't reach an HTML element from PHP in a "scripty way".

Comment: Unless you were to read and parse an HTML file through PHP, that is :) (just pulling your leg)

Comment: @nico thought about this, but what a nightmare :P

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness - if you *really*, **really** want to do this, you can read about [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/pl/book.outcontrol.php) and [DOM manipulation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). That way you can manipulate your HTML document with all features provided by DOM server-side, while it is on its way to client's browser.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reach it at all from PHP; if you want to manipulate it in the browser then you must use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reach it from php , but you can do it by using javascript .

Answer (score 0):

There are no stupid questions when you're starting out!

Here's a slightly more hands on attempt at explaining how php and html interact. Say you have a file called filename.html, lets say there are a bunch of html tags in this file and nothing else.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div> <p> This content is completely static </p> </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

As you can see, the content in this file is completely static, and if you want to change anything you have to do it manually. Say you want to introduce dynamic content, this is where php comes in.

Rename the file with the php extension, so its filename.php, now you can add php tags  and insert php code between these tags and this content is dynamically rendered. For example:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div> <p> This content is completely static </p> </div>

    <div> <?php 
             $dynamicContent = "<p>This content is dynamic</p>";
             echo $dynamicContent;
          ?> 
   </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

PHP enables the content in the second  tag to be dynamic, read from a database etc etc. Obviously this is an extremely simple case and for this to work on your local machine you would need a webserver that knows the path to your php installation.

Hope this helps...